# Referencing an object property with numeric value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, reference

I've run into a - what seems - somewhat strange problem. Let's say I have a JavaScript object like this one:

```
var Object = {
    Property1: 0,
    Property2: 1,
    TxtProperty: "Sample text",

    Update: function () {
        this.Property1++;                      // Doesn't work
        Object.Property2++;                    // Does work
        this.TxtProperty = "Hello world";      // Does work

        $('#prop-1').text(this.Property1);     // Prints NaN
        $('#prop-2').text(Object.Property2);   // Prints correct value
        $('#txt-prop').text(this.TxtProperty); // Prints correct value
    }
};
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wC2uM/1/) for a demonstration. Click 'Start' to start the timer and update the values. As you can see, using `parseInt` didn't help either.

I've tested this in Firefox, Chrome, and IE10. They all show the same behavior.

Why can't you reference a property with a numeric value using `this` from inside another property with a function value? Why does it work with non-numeric values? Is this a bug or is this intended?

This is not so much a real problem as we can simply use the parent object's name to update the numeric value, but I'm just curious as to why this is so.

Comment: I think `this` will refer to Window the way you use it. Not to parent object.

Comment: But then surely `this.TxtProperty` shouldn't work either.

Comment: It work because it creates a new `window.TxtProperty` property.

Comment: Try looking at `Object.TxtProperty` after that, you'll see that it didn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` runs the function in the `window` context so `this` inside of it refers to `window`. If you `bind` the proper `this` context, then it'll work fine:

```
interval = setInterval(Object.Update.bind(Object), 1000);
                                     -----^------
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wC2uM/2/

`bind` only works in modern browsers so if you need support for old IE use an anonymous function:

```
interval = setInterval(function(){ Object.Update(); }, 1000);
```

Remember that in JavaScript `this` depends on how you **call** the function; it's mutable.

Comment: You can simplify `Object.Update.call(Object);` to `Object.Update();` ;)